# Как написать функцию, которая принимает число и возвращает его положительным?

Tags: javascript

Напишите функцию с именем positive, которая принимает число и возвращает его положительным. Если число является положительным, то возвращается само число.
Примеры:

```
функция positive(10) должна возвратить 10;
функция positive(0) должна возвратить 0;
функция positive(-2) должна возвратить 2;

function positive(num){
return num;
}
console.log(positive(10));
console.log(positive(0));
10 и 0 возвращает, как вернуть 2 ?
```

Comment: Читайте про `if` в абсолютно любом учебнике по javascript...

Answer (score 3):

Ну если не использовать функцию Math.abs, то можно сделать так:

```
function positive(num){
   return num >= 0 ? num : num * -1;
}
```

Или так:

```
function positive(num){
   if(num >= 0){
      return num
   }else{
      return num * -1
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function positive(num){
  return Math.abs(num);
}

console.log(positive(10))
console.log(positive(-2))
```

Предлагаю попробовать вот такой вариант

Answer (score 0):

```
function positive(num){
return Math.abs(num);
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]